# How to access a variable from an ajax/jquery POST rather than a GET

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, flask

This is probably a simple question but I cannot figure it out.

If I have an update route like this:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    x = request.args.get('foo')
    print(x)
    ...
```

and jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#foobar").click(function() {

      $.ajax({
              url: '/update',
              type: "GET",
              data: { foo: 'hello stack exchange!'}
            });
  });

});
```

I can access message and set it equal to x and then it prints out `hello stack exchange!`

but if I change the request to POST rather than GET how do I access it?

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    x = request['foo'] # THIS DOESN'T WORK
    print(x)
    ...
```

and jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#foobar").click(function() {

      $.ajax({
              url: '/update',
              type: "POST",
              data: { foo: 'hello stack exchange!'}
            });
  });

});
```

I understand the payload is not going through the URL so I need to change `request.args.get('foo')` to something else but if `request['foo']` doesn't work then what will?

Comment: Do you try to use `request.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the common ways of getting the request data.

[`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.form) the key/value pairs in the body, from post-action form, or XHR request that isn't encoded. [`request.values`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.values) combined `args` and `form`, preferring `args` if duplicate keys exist. [`request.json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.json) request JSON data. The request must have the content-type `application/json`. what you are probably looking for is `request.values.get('foo')`.

Answer (score 0):

use `request.get_json()` for get json

```
if request.is_json:
   data = request.get_json()
   foo= req_data['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

for post request, where is the parameter stored depend on the Content-Type header of the request

- if Content-Type=application/json, you can get the parameter with "request.json" (as a dict)
- if Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded', you can get the parameter with "request.form" (as a dict)
  ----I guess this is your scenario,
- otherwise , you may want to try request.data(as a string)